# Debugging Ionic 2 in Visual Studio Code - How to Hit Breakpoints in Source Files?

Tags: ionic-framework, visual-studio-code, ionic2

**Problem:** 
Breakpoints are only being hit in the concatenated build file www\build\js\app.bundle.js

**Reproduce**

1. I start the emulator, run the app on the emulator (this works perfectly)
2. Set some breakpoints in app folder files e.g. `app/pages/list/list.js`
3. In VS Code>Debug Pane, I choose `Attach to running Android on Emulator`. Debugger runs and connects.

**Actual Result**

3. The breakpoints are not hit in the original source files. They only get hit if I set them in the  build js file `www\build\js\app.bundle.js`

**Note on Sourcemaps**

In `MyIonic2Project\.vscode\launch.json`, the settings for the Attach to Running on Emulator configuration are:

```
"sourceMaps": true,
"cwd": "${workspaceRoot}",
"ionicLiveReload": false
```

---

**My Setup**

It's an Ionic 2 project, created using:

```
ionic start --v2 -a "My Ionic 2" MyIonic2Project tutorial
```

This works perfect with cli commands: on Chrome with `ionic serve`, emulator using `ionic emulate android`, and on the device as well (HTC One M8), so all is good up to this point :-)

I have installed latest *Visual Studio Code*, and included the Cordova tools: `ext install cordova-tools`

Comment: https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-cordova/issues/92  - "We do not fully support ionic 2 at the moment. Ionic 2 projects are structured differently to ionic 1"

Comment: Also due to https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/6930

Comment: Update July 2016 - This is being worked on at the moment. Issue: https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-cordova/issues/92#issuecomment-233109904, Pull Request: https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-cordova/pull/173

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I have extra info, but too long to put in comment, so putting in as answer. Give feedback if updates needed.

From the Ionic 2 forums, the following is a link to a tutorial for Debugging directly in VSCode TypeScript files.

Uses Ionic CLI extension, for brevity. Also need Debugger for Chrome extension for VSCode.

**Debugging Ionic 2 Apps in Chrome from Visual Studio Code**
http://www.damirscorner.com/blog/posts/20161122-DebuggingIonic2AppsInChromeFromVisualStudioCode.html

**Update**:
See @Kinorsi comment for details on getting this to work for mobile

There is a related issue on GitHub - which has been `Closed`, which may be worth noting. Resolution was Ionic 2 RC build system is no longer using gulp. There is also a further comment regarding the use of inline sourcemaps `"ionic_source_map_type": "#inline-source-map"`:
[TypeScript source files cannot be debugged on a real mobile device in Android #22](https://github.com/driftyco/ionic-gulp-tasks/issues/22)

Comment: The post works for chrome. But how to make it work on device? I can't make break point work with my genimotion emulator...

Comment: @Kinorsi That I don't know. I have seen an issue raised about mobile device debugging of TS files on the ionic github, havn't got a link right now though, but worth searching for

Comment: I got the answer from the post author in the comments: To get it working, I had to add the --dev switch to ionic:build script in package.json, as suggested in this GitHub [issue](https://github.com/driftyco/ionic-app-scripts/issues/407#issuecomment-261986697):

`"ionic:build": "ionic-app-scripts build --dev"`

Comment: @Kinorsi Great stuff!

Comment: What about ionic 3?

Comment: @Yerkon No idea about Ionic 3... I don't use Ionic. Maybe someone could add a new answer for v3

Answer (score 6):

Well, this question is a bit old, so VSCode changed a lot since then. It works almost right of the box now, and the sourcemaps work too. Tested with Ionic3.

1 - **Install the Cordova Tools extension** for Visual Studio Code.

2 - Generate a *launch.json* file by selecting "Cordova" environment in the Debug Panel.
[image]

After that, debugging on Chrome works if you run "Serve to the browser (ionic serve)".

3 - If you want to make it work with an iOS simulator or device, you'll need to install the [iOS Webkit Debug Proxy](https://github.com/google/ios-webkit-debug-proxy).

I struggled for so long to make this work that I did an entire article on my blog to make it simpler for others: https://geeklearning.io/live-debug-your-cordova-ionic-application-with-visual-studio-code/

With this, you can debug on chrome, simulators and real devices with Ionic livereload!
I'm still having some issues sometimes, but I hope this helps.